# What does cmd = 0x84 does in ADS7830 ADC

Tags: pi-3

What does `cmd=0x84` do in `ADS7830` `ADC`. Its binary value is `10000100`

```
class ADS7830(ADCDevice):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ADS7830, self).__init__()
        self.cmd = 0x84
        self.address = 0x4b # 0x4b is the default i2c address for ADS7830 Module.   
        
    def analogRead(self, chn): # ADS7830 has 8 ADC input pins, chn:0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
        value = self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, self.cmd|(((chn<<2 | chn>>1)&0x07)<<4))
        return value
```

Comment: have you tried searching for a datasheet for ADS7830?

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.